# Chrome: css transition animations finish immediately when Developer Tools opens

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a long transform:translate transition on my website (the position bar for an audio player). The reason I chose to set a css transition for this is because this is the smoothest way (instead of js animation).

When I open the developer window during transition, the transition jumps to the final state (so the transition is gone). I'm sure this is one of the many problematic Chrome rendering quirks but I'm looking for the best way to solve this. Or is it unsolvable?

On request I can provide a code example.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Debug this animation using DevTools? Or you just don't like the fact that animation "jumps" when you open DT?

Comment: I don't like the fact that it jumps to the final position. It makes the audio position bar jump to the end, while the playing track can still be somewhere in the middle (so the position bar show a wrong current position) Normal visitors normally don't open DT but it can happen, and anyway opening up DT should not break an audio player.